# Preventing browser loading indicator with Chrome + GWT-rpc

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

I'm writing a ajax chatting webapp, just to test working with GWT.

To simulate server side push of chat messages from the server to the browser, I have a XHR request running behind. It all works fine - except on Chrome, the browser is displaying a loading icon (a spinner) because of the XHR request on background.

Is there any way to avoid this? I've tested it in Firefox, and it doesn't display such behavior.

EDIT - I found the solution. http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/a0330cb47e05c485?fwc=2

quoting the GWT groiup post:

> Chrome shows the loading indicator if connection was made immediately 
>   from the "body onload()", i.e. from onModuleLoad().

Comment: If you found the answer to your question, post it below as an answer and mark it as approved - that way others will benefit from it too (and you'll get a badge ;)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome shows the loading indicator if connection was made immediately from the "body onload()", i.e. from onModuleLoad().

Answer (score 0):

No, there is now way to disable this.

All AJAX requests cause Chrome to display this. I'm guessing it's for security reasons. (The user is aware of any AJAX requests that he/she might not be aware of.) Also, it indicates that data is being fetched - a type of status indicator.

Comment: Then how does the existing applications, such as gmail chat, work?

Comment: I don't use gmail chat, so I can't answer that.